# Can AWS CloudFormation use conditions inside the Metadata dealing with Parameters Stack Screen?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an `If/Else` statement inside the High Level Object `Metadata`. It works as it should in the `Resources` level, but in the Parameter screen when running the stack it shows all of the parameters. Maybe it is not possible. When the option is True it shows the parameters, but when it is false it will hide them. At default it is false

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: AWS CloudFormation Bucket Info
        Parameters:
          - pOption
          - pS3BucketName
          - pS3KeyPrefix
    ParameterLabels:
      pOption:
        default: Do you want to run this option
      pS3BucketName:
        default: S3 Bucket
      pS3KeyPrefix:
        default: S3 Key Prefix
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
Parameters:
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you get a solution ?

Comment: Nope, but have been working with AWS on this issue.

Comment: Okay.. Keep us updated :)

Comment: It's been a while but have you ever resolved this? It doesn't just affect top level metadata but cfn-init metadata as well.

Comment: I have been doing a hack of this. I write a condition and based on that condition, I a set of parameters within mapping. It does work, but not like I want it to. No news from AWS on this.